# Convert string (0:2:1) to time format in PHP

Tags: php

This is very simple but I can't find a function to format string to time format.

I have the following string that want to format it to time:

0:2:1

How can I make it 00:02:01?

Comment: Well, `0:2:1` isn't really a valid time format. It's just numbers separated by a colon. Try smashing it apart with a hammer, padding each piece with a 0, then gluing them back together.

Comment: i'm so clueless. what is the function to format each time w/ zero? i have a variable hours, minutes and seconds. if i can just format it like format($seconds, "00")) that will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a simple little script:

```
$input = '0:2:1';
$split = explode(':', $input);
foreach ($split as $i => $v) $split[$i] = str_pad($v, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$final = implode(':', $split);
echo $final; // Do something with the new string you created
```

This will take any string such as `0:2:1`, `0:3:15`, or `10:4:9` and create a string in the proper time format of `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

> i'm so clueless. what is the function to format each time w/ zero? i have a variable hours, minutes and seconds. if i can just format it like format($seconds, "00")) that will work for me.

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```